# Ruby solution for finding the most similar numerical data sets or curves?

Tags: ruby, math, statistics

I'm trying to find the best/closest matching candidate dataset relative to a target dataset.  Below is a sample dataset.  Note that higher values do not mean "better", so the deviation is being calculated as an absolute value.

**Sample dataset:**

[image: Graph of table]

The above graph illustrates the problem where **Candidate A** is a "better" match than **Candidate B** even though the cumulative deviation of **A's** data points are actually greater relative to the **Target**.

Adding up each of the point deviations from the target (Euclidean distance) seemed reasonable at first, however, this doesn't account for large deviations of a single point that might exclude a Candidate altogether.  I'd prefer to avoid adding arbitrary cutoffs or discarding outliers for any one data point.

Here's the Ruby implementation of the illustration above:

```
target     = [0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80]
candidates = {
  a: [0.88, 0.72, 0.84, 0.85, 0.88, 0.93, 0.65, 0.90, 0.95],
  b: [0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.00, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80]
}
distance   = { a: 0.0, b: 0.0 }

candidates.each do |candidate, values|
  values.each_with_index do |value, index|
    distance[candidate] += (value - target[index]).abs
  end
  puts "Distance #{candidate.upcase}: #{distance[candidate]}"
end

=> Distance A: 0.86
=> Distance B: 0.80
```

So, I'm looking for better ways to penalize larger deviations or generalize the match (or a way of defining what a "better" fit is).  Averages?  Squares?  Gaussian filtering?

Are there any Ruby gems that already have lots of useful stats algorithms for doing just this sort of thing?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a common statistical issue, but it doesn't seem to have much to do with Ruby, or any programming language for that matter.

Comment: Least squares fitting will calculate the set of coefficients that minimize the sum of squared errors.  Try that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Well, I'd like a Ruby gem solution that let's me try a broad range of options quickly, unless of course it's something that's reasonably quick to implement outside a gem (don't want to re-invent the wheel).  Thx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be interested in [linefit](https://github.com/escline/linefit)

If you do a lot of computational programming in Ruby, you might want to look into the [SciRuby](http://gems.sciruby.com/) gems.

In the future if you're looking for gem recommendations, check out [awesome-ruby](http://awesome-ruby.com/). It's a pretty solid collection of really useful gems.